# Adding second product to an opportunity if a specific product is first added

Tags: validation-rule, opportunity-lineitem, product

I have 65 products all under the same family spread across 4 sub families.

- Product 01-20 = SubFamily1 / Chair
- Product 21-40 = SubFamily2 / Desk
- Product 41-60 = SubFamily3 / Conference table
- Product 61-65 = SubFamily4 / Setup fees

When a user adds a product to an opportunity I need a second product added from the 4th sub family dependent upon what they selected in the first 3 families.  There are a few that do not need the second product.

Examples:

- User selects product02 I need to automagically add product61
- User selects product05 no second product needed
- User selects product33 I need to automagically add product62

I know my way around SF enough to get by but this is pushing me into learning something new.  Can this be done with validation rules?  Should these products be setup differently as far as family/sub family?

Comment: VR won't work on Oppo by looking down into Oppo Products; VR on Oppo can only look at Oppo and Oppo parent fields

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot do this with Validation rules. There is no standard, out of the box functionality for this.
You need to add some customization (Apex, Triggers, and also data model relationship between products) to achieve this.

Comment: Lots to learn from what it sounds like.  lol  Thank you for your response.  Would the trailheads help out with this at all or is there somewhere else that I could go to learn more?

Comment: Trailhead is the best place to go to. It will also helps you to know as to which feature needs to be used in what cases.